# How to remove underscore between two numbers in all files in a directory

Tags: bash, filenames, rename, mv

So I have a directory with nested folders, and at some point there are `.png` images.

The naming of these images is like this "letters_numbers_numbers_letters.png", and I want to delete the underscore between the numbers.

Say that we have a file named `a_1_2_b.png`, I want to rename it to `a_12_b.png`.
I know I have to use something like:

```
find . -name "*[0-9]_[0-9]* -type f -exec bash -c <enter_code here>`
```

but I'm not sure how to specify how to delete this specific underscore. Remember there are two other underscores I don't want to touch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one of the variants of `perl`'s `rename`. For instance, with [that one](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename) (`rename` package in Debian-like systems):

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*[0-9]_[0-9]*' -type f -exec rename -n -d '
  s/(?<=\d)_(?=\d)//g' {} +
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) when happy).

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
autoload -Uz # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n  '(**/)(*[0-9]_[0-9]*)(#qD.)' \
        '$1${2//(#m)[0-9][_0-9]#[0-9]/${MATCH//_}}'
```

It's a bit more complicated, as there's no equivalent of perl's look-around regexp operators in zsh globs.

Those remove all the `_`s that are surrounded by digits in every regular file's name (would rename the `dir_1_2_3/file_1_2_foo_22_3_4_bar` file to `dir_1_2_3/file_12_foo_2234_bar` for instance).

To only remove the second `_` in regular files that follow the `letters_digits_digits_letters.png` pattern, that would just be:

```
zmv -n '(**/)([[:alpha:]]##_<->)_(<->_[[:alpha:]]##.png)(#qD.)' \
       '$1$2$3'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I'm refering to the first solution. I tried it to some files i made for test, and no problems there, so I went on with the real thing and all went smooth.

Comment: You used `LC_ALL=C`  - are there really locales with non-digit characters between 0 and 9 or is this a habit of prudence?

Comment: @FelixJN, there are certainly systems and locales where `[0-9]` matches a lot more than 0123456789, though it's often characters that have something to do with digits (like digits in other scripts or things like `²` or ``), but here that `LC_ALL=C` is more so that `*` matches any sequence of bytes.